# In my HTML, the MySQL entry I'm calling using PHP only brings first word

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have looked at other threads for this, but they all talk about when you're echoing the data from within the PHP area of the code, I'm trying to do it through the HTML area.

It currently brings only the first word of the target, how can I get all words?

I have tried the extra quotes technique, it doesn't work for me.

```
<strong>Sales Rep : </strong> <input type="text" name="user_name" value=<?php echo $u_name; ?> /><br/>
```

Comment: It should be `value="<?php echo $u_name; ?>"`

Comment: @bub maybe it is, but consistency is key.

Comment: It seems to me the problem is not where you echo the $u_name variable but where it is created.

Comment: the value attribute should be wrapped in quotes :p

Comment: @ArtOsi - Thank you very much, that solved it, very simply also. I believe my issue was I was putting the quotation marks in the wrong place. When I did it without quotation marks it didn't work, I suppose because it's in the html itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at the HTML output?

Using your code:

```
$u_name = 'John Doe';
<input type="text" name="user_name" value=<?php echo $u_name; ?> /><br/>
```

Will output:

```html
<input type="text" name="user_name" value=John doe />
```

To make the browser show the full name it should be:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="John Doe" />
```

Note the added quotes (") surrounding the name.

So your PHP should be:

```
$u_name = 'John Doe';
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $u_name; ?>" /><br/>
```

Will output :

```html
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="John doe" /><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it, same as I mentioned to ArtOsi!